# Javascript problem - not passing string with leading '0' to string properly

Tags: php, javascript, string

I have a weird problem.
I have a simple function to open a popup with information about a pin (by clicking on a link with that PIN)

It works fine for some pins, but converts others to a different number.

For example passing '033604' opens
http://mysite.com/pincheck.php?pin=014212

but passing '023960'
opens
http://mysite.com/pincheck.php?pin=023960   (what I need)

Passing '032765' opens
http://mysite.com/pincheck.php?pin=013813

but passing '030309'
opens
http://mysite.com/pincheck.php?pin=030309 (what I need)

I've tried a bunch of pins and it's all random like that - either passes the correct pin or converts it to a different number

The function is

```
function win_open_pin(pin) {
newwindow = window.open('pincheck.php?pin=' + '0' + pin + '' , 'popupwin', 'menubar=no,history=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,width=650,height=300');
if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
}
```

I did try using pincheck.php?pin=0' + pin
and did try pin = toString(pin) in the function - no use

The call is also simple

```
<a href=\"javascript:win_open_pin($pin)\">$pin</a>
```

The $pin variable in php is taken from the db and is a string, I even did (string) casting just in case.
It seems to be js issue, as I never had issues like that with php.

I don't see any rhyme or reason to this. Hope someone can point me in the right direction to solve this.
Thanks.

Comment: When you do a "view source" on your page, what exactly does that `<a>` tag look like?  Note that regardless of the data type of "$pin" in php, if you drop it into that function call without quotes around it, then JavaScript is going to consider it to be a number ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its an issue with the automatic int conversion.
e.g:

```
parseInt("033604", 10) //returns 33604

parseInt("033604") //returns 14212 - Octal
```

Change the anchor element markup to following(notice the single quotes around $pin):

```
<a href=\"javascript:win_open_pin('$pin')\">$pin</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, it fixed it indeed, the previous answer was pretty much the same

Answer (score 1):

DEC 013813 = OCT 032765
Javascript assumes a number is Octal if it starts with a leading zero.[Description](http://javascript.about.com/library/blnumbase.htm). Adding quotes around $pin should resolve the issue for you.